# How to set culture / locale in Symfony depending on subdomain?

Tags: symfony, localization

I'm using Symfony 2.1 and I'd like to know if there is a way to set culture / locale depending on subdomain.

Example:

us.xxxxxxxxx.com -> English for USA (en_US)
uk.xxxxxxxxx.com -> English for UK (en_GB)
es.xxxxxxxxx.com -> Spanish for Spain (es_ES)
ar.xxxxxxxxx.com -> Spanish for Argentina (es_AR)

I mean, in wildcards I could get the country and then set a culture and locale to the site.

I've read the documentation of Symfony 2.1 but I couldn't understand how I should do it.

Comment: I would highly recommend [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) for that task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Crozin. I've been using JMSI18nRoutingBundle for the last two hours but I couldn't make it work properly. The documentation isn't much complete. Do you have any example of how I should configure it?

Answer (score 0):

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [en, de]
    strategy: custom
    hosts:
        en: en.foo.com
        de: de.foo.com
    redirect_to_host: true
```

Comment: Thanks @Max. I've already done this before but when I enter "de.foo.com" it redirects me to "en.foo.com". I mean, it always shows the english page. If a set redirect_to_host to false it gives me a 404 error. I think there's something missing in my config. Do I have to change anything in my bundle routing part?